# Accessing the Primavera data using Primavera Integration API and a python script

Tags: python-3.x, primavera, product-management

I want to develop a python script to retrieve data from the Primavera API for my firm. I do not have any idea where to start.I saw a couple of articles where getting data from API's was fairly simple task using few lines of python code. However this doesn't seem to be the case here.
Can anyone please help!

Comment: Why aren't the python examples you've seen working for you? Are you trying to pull different data? It'd be useful to provide additional information about what information, specifically, you're looking to query. In addition, it would help focus the answers if you provided a list of what web service or API calls you were trying to work with, and what the results were.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out.
But Primavera is a paid software, and I was asked to get access to all the personal projects etc of a particular firm. 
I tried installing the API and running it on my SQL server. But it was throwing an error saying that the login credentials are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Primavera P6 API uses Java, so you have 3 choices:

1. Use Python Java bridge
2. Write the code in Java
3. Use Python to connect to Primavera P6 Web Services (another Primavera integration technology)

Comment: Given the wording of the question, I'd assume the OP is trying to pursue the third option. Can you provide an example of what the python code would look like to access the data? At minimum, providing a quick overview of the relevant web service end points would probably help the OP solve the issue.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Unfortunately I am expert in Primavera P6 and Java but not in Python and I do not use Primavera P6 Web Services due to more complexity and less speed, so there is no example I can provide right now and OP should either wait for someone else or try to dig into the problem himself.

Comment: Hey. So my client's firms have the primavera software, but my firm doesn't. They want to retrieve the client's data using the API, even though they haven't purchased the software

Comment: @GautamShah So there are not only programming but also licensing issues. I think you should search for some Primavera P6 developers' training (not sure if Oracle has them actually).